# How to escape $ in the value of the field

Tags: json, conditional-statements, jq

Need to get value of `id` that corresponds **`name='robot$deployer'`**. How can `$` be escaped so `jq` only select corrct ID (1321) instead of both (1321 and 1326)? Currently script below with print both IDs

```
[
  {
    "id": 1321,
    "name": "robot$deployer",
    "token": "",
    "description": "deployer",
    "project_id": 55,
    "expires_at": 1590799816,
    "disabled": false,
    "creation_time": "2020-04-29T10:50:16.029882-07:00",
    "update_time": "2020-04-29T10:50:16.029882-07:00"
  },
  {
    "id": 1326,
    "name": "robot$test",
    "token": "",
    "description": "test",
    "project_id": 55,
    "expires_at": 1590862956,
    "disabled": false,
    "creation_time": "2020-04-30T04:22:36.940445-07:00",
    "update_time": "2020-04-30T04:22:36.940445-07:00"
  }
]
```

test script

```sh
#!/bin/bash

export PROJECT_INFO='[ { "id": 1321, "name": "robot$deployer", "token": "", "description": "deployer", "project_id": 55, "expires_at": 1590799816, "disabled": false, "creation_time": "2020-04-29T10:50:16.029882-07:00", "update_time": "2020-04-29T10:50:16.029882-07:00" }, { "id": 1326, "name": "robot$test", "token": "", "description": "test", "project_id": 55, "expires_at": 1590862956, "disabled": false, "creation_time": "2020-04-30T04:22:36.940445-07:00", "update_time": "2020-04-30T04:22:36.940445-07:00" } ]'

ROBOT_LOGIN="robot\$deployer"
export ROBOT_ID=$(echo $PROJECT_INFO | jq --arg robot_name "$ROBOT_LOGIN" 'if .[].name == "robot$deployer" then .[].id else empty end')
echo "ROBOT_ID:" $ROBOT_ID
```

**Updated working version of the script**, thx @[hobbs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/152948/hobbs)

```sh
export PROJECT_INFO='[ { "id": 1321, "name": "robot$deployer", "token": "", "description": "deployer", "project_id": 55, "expires_at": 1590799816, "disabled": false, "creation_time": "2020-04-29T10:50:16.029882-07:00", "update_time": "2020-04-29T10:50:16.029882-07:00" }, { "id": 1326, "name": "robot$test", "token": "", "description": "test", "project_id": 55, "expires_at": 1590862956, "disabled": false, "creation_time": "2020-04-30T04:22:36.940445-07:00", "update_time": "2020-04-30T04:22:36.940445-07:00" } ]'

ROBOT_LOGIN="robot\$deployer"
export ROBOT_ID=$(echo $PROJECT_INFO | jq --arg rl "${ROBOT_LOGIN}" '.[] | select(.name == $rl) | .id')
echo "ROBOT_ID:" $ROBOT_ID
```

Comment: You don't have a problem with escaping. The `$` doesn't need any escaping. It's just that your `if ... then .[].id else empty end` is incorrect. `.[].id` evaluates to *all* of the IDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you were trying to do is handled by the jq `select` function:

```
ROBOT_ID=$(jq '.[] | select(.name == "robot$deployer") | .id')
```